# Can't resolve [module path] in [path]. Compiler doesn't recognize the import alias

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

I've seen numerous topics related to this issue but no advice really helped my cause.
I'm setting up an environment with CRA, using TS Redux template (`npx create-react-app project-tracker --template cra-template-redux-typescript`).
I want to have components in the 'src/components/ui/[ComponentName]' folder structure and I want to access 'src/components' with alias '@/components'.

For example, `import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";` when Button is exported in the button.tsx like so `export { Button, buttonVariants }`.

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Within the VSCode, imports work well, the editor recognizes all the paths.
However, after running npm start, I get errors:

```
ERROR in ./src/App.tsx 6:0-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/components/ui/button' in '/Users/[userName]/Documents/priv/project-tracker/src'
```

I've tried various combination of paths and baseUrl. Used babel as well but to no avail. Is there some stupid mistake I'm making in the tsconfig?